# Open a file in the directory Resources

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, path, resources, directory

I want to open an included html file in the Resources directory, but it seems like my path is wrong or I am making some other mistake.

I am currently in a form class and I want to open the file if the user presses the button F1.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "f1.html";
proc.Start();
```

Comment: What do you mean with "Resources directory"? Application resources or some physical directory in you hard drive?

Comment: What is the error? Is it in run time or compile time? Have you removed that parenthesis?

Comment: I mean Application Resources. The error is File not Found and yes i removed them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get some embedded resource, you need to call

```
ResourceManager.GetStream
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxee5096.aspx

It will return a memory stream. Read the memory stream to a byte array and write the byte array to some temp location and then invoke

```
Process.Start()
```

using the path of the temp file as argument.

Here is a sample code:

```
public class Class1{
    public static void Main(string[] args){
        FileStream stream = null;
        string fullTempPath = null;
        try{
            byte[] page = Resources.HTMLPage1;
            fullTempPath = Path.GetTempPath() + Guid.NewGuid() + ".html";
            stream = new FileStream(fullTempPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read);
            stream.Write(page, 0, page.Length);
            stream.Flush(true);
            stream.Close();
            Process proc = new Process{StartInfo ={FileName = fullTempPath}};
            proc.Start();
        }
        finally{
            if (stream != null){
                stream.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why is it so difficult to open a file .. and why i have to write it to a temp location. Could you give me a full example?

Comment: @user3438236 It's not so dificult, is just a metter of following some steps. I Have updated my answer with sample code. I had added a resource to the project in binary format called HTMLPage1.htm for the sample to work. I suggest writing in temp to ensure you have writing right in the directory.

Comment: this does not work for me: byte[] page = Resources.HTMLPage1;         It seems like i can't use Resources.

Comment: @user3438236 Of course this line won't work for you, as I said before, I added a resource to my project named HTMLPage1. You must replace this with the name of the resource in your  project, as it will have a different name in your project.

Comment: yeah i did that. I've already added the Resource or HTML Page but i can't use Resources.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to open an html file using the default browser

```
        string filename = Environment.CurrentDirectory + System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "f1.html";

        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(filename);
```